# scale factors of GL_SRC_ALPHA in glBlendFunc

Tags: opengl

[Kronos web-page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml) says that blending methods specified by `GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, etc.` define four scale factors for each of the three color channels plus the alpha channel. In particular, scale factors for `GL_SRC_ALPHA` are computed as follows:

[image]

Where `A_s0` is alpha value of the source, and `kA` is computed as follows:
[image], where m_c is the number of respective red, green, blue, or alpha bitplanes.

1. **I was wondering what are these bitplanes?**
2. **Why is kA computed according to the aforementioned formula?**

For instance, it is clear for me what happens when there is 1 source with `GL_SRC_ALPHA` and 1 destination with `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`, whose blending factors are simply 1 minus the above mentioned values. If kA=1, then the blending is a linear interpolation between colors from source and destination, weighted by their alpha values, i.e. `alpha_s * source_color + (1-alpha_s) * destination_color`. **How does kA comes into play in here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, all of that is describing the process of [unsigned integer normalization](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Normalized_Integer): the conversion of integer values to floating-point values on the range [0, 1]. That page is written assuming that all of the values in question are integers. Since blending happens with floating-point values, integers have to be normalzied before any computations can take place.

`kA` is just the number of bits in that particular color channel (what they call the number of "bitplanes"). The division by `kA` maps values on the integer range [0, kA] to the floating-point range [0, 1].

What's probably confusing you is that, in *modern* OpenGL, the source values are not *integers*. The values you output from your fragment shader are floats. The destination values in the framebuffer may be floats or normalized integers, but if they're normalized, they get mapped to [0, 1] before the blending equation gets to them.

Basically, that page was never really updated to fit into modern OpenGL. Or even OpenGL 2.0. It's best to ignore it and [use something else](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending).